# How to filter by array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    type: "Sword",
    name: "ABC",
    description: 'ABC',
    rarities: [
      {
        rarity: 'Common',
        damage: 100
      },
      {
        rarity: 'Uncommon',
        damage: 200
      },
      {
        rarity: 'Rare',
        damage: 300
      }
   ]
}...
```

and the following filtering code:

```
const string = "Search query";
const keys = ['type', 'name', 'rarity'];
this.setState({
   data: data.filter(entry => keys.some(k => entry[k]
     .toString()
     .toLowerCase()
     .includes(string)
   ))
})
```

which doesn't work and says `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`. It works if I remove the `'rarities'` key but I am unable to get it to filter based on objects in the rarities array too. The idea is that the user should be able to search and filter a table where the type, name or rarity inside rarities equals the entered search value. Does someone know what im supposed to do, do I need to do additional fintering for objects within the array?

Comment: `rarity` is not a property of the `entry` object.

Comment: First of all, you are doing too much in a single line of code. You should break your code into multiple lines by assigning intermediate steps to variables. Then you can debug your code to see what's going on.

Comment: It's not JSON - it's a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when checking for the key rarity: `entry[k]` where k = rarity `entry[rarity]` , at this point

```
keys.some(k => entry[k]
 .toString()
 .toLowerCase()
 .includes(string)
```

)

will look like:

```
keys.some(k => entry['rarity']
 .toString()
 .toLowerCase()
 .includes(string)
```

)

`entry['rarity']` doesn't exist so its `undefined` so basically its trying to do `undefined.toString()....` .  rarity is nested inside `rarities`. So to access this you would have to be looking inside `entry['rarities']['rarity']`

You could try importing lodash `https://lodash.com/` and then use lodash's _.get method to have something like :

```
const string = "Search query";
const keys = ['type', 'name', 'rarities.rarity'];
this.setState({
   data: data.filter(entry => keys.some(k => _.get(entry, k)
     .toString()
     .toLowerCase()
     .includes(string)
   ))
})
```

see that for your keys `rarity` is now `rarities.rarity`
this should work